# MFC: Creating modeless dialog box without displaying

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc

I'm trying to create a simple modeless dialog box which I'm creating from my CWinApp derived InitInstance() function.

```
BOOL CMyApp::InitInstance()
{
    ...
    m_pMyDialog = new CMyDialog();
    m_pMyDialog->Create(CMyDialog::IDD);
    ...
    retrun TRUE;
}
```

I've created the dialog template in the resource editor and the WS_VISIBLE bit is unset. My intention is to avoid showing the dialog until I explicitly call ShowWindow(SW_SHOW) but for some reason the call to Create displays the dialog.

I've tried to change the return value of OnInitDialog() to FALSE but that doesn't work.

I've even tried to call ModifyStyle() in case something else is setting the WS_VISIBLE bit.

```
int CMyDialog::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct) 
{
   if (CDialog::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1)
      return -1;

   ModifyStyle(WS_VISIBLE, 0);   

   return 0;

 }
```

That doesn't work either. In all cases, after I call Create the dialog is displayed which isn't how I've read it should work.

Comment: I know I can call ShowWindow(SW_HIDE) after calling Create(...) but that causes the dialog box to flash on the screen momentarily and that isn't ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with AnimateWindow() which was causing the dialog to display prematurely.

Comment: You never mentioned AnimateWindow in the question which made it impossible to figure out. Still, thanks for coming back with the answer.